# C++\CX для не отображается xaml форма в конструкторе

Tags: c++, visual-studio, xaml

Не отображается форма в c++\cx приложение, при запуске форма работает. Проект создаю новый, ошибок не пишет никаких, кроме конструктора. Подскажите как решить проблему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Page
    x:Class="App4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```